# CSS box shadow psudo element showing under background image

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

Can someone tell me why the shadow underneath my blue background is showing?

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Small Business HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Global Classes */

/* centered columns styles */

.row-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* reset the text-align */
  text-align: left;
  /* inline-block space fix */
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.shadow-full {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.shadow-full:before,
.shadow-full:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 430px / 30px;
}
.shadow-sides {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.shadow-sides:before,
.shadow-sides:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0px;
}
hr:not(.white) {
  background: #a12816;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
.white hr {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.fullrule-medium {
  border-top: 13px solid #a12816;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%
}
.fullrule-thin {
  border-top: 8px solid #a12816;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
}
.container.whitespace {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
/* Subcategories */

.subcats .container {
  padding: 27px 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.subcats h2 {
  color: #E0B754;
  text-indent: 16px;
}
.subcats ul li > a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}
.subcats ul i {
  color: white;
}
/* Main Banner Container */

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
  color: #005da7;
  margin: 30 0 30;
}
.banner-head > .row.header {
  height: 500px;
}
.banner-head img {
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
.banner-head {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
/* join_bar */

.join_bar > p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
/* well attributes */

.well.container-fluid {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
.well [class~=col] {
  padding: 0;
}
.well {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 64px 0 20px;
}
.well .container h4,
.well .container span {
  color: #005DA7;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.well .img-block {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.9);
  width: 200px;
}
.well .img-block img {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.well .text-block {
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.well h2,
.well a {
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* Blog Panels */

.blog-panel {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: url("/img/patt-bg.jpg");
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
.blog-panel > .blue-bg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.blog-panel .row {
  margin: 0;
}
.blog-panel .panel {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  min-height: 170px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.blog-panel .panel h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.blog-panel .panel p {
  height: auto;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0;
}
.blog-panel .container-fluid {
  max-width: 1234px;
  position: relative;
}
.blog-panel .btn {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.blog-panel .panel .img-rounded {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 140px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Posts Panel */

.posts {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.posts > .panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.panel:after {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
/* Deal Panels*/

.deal-content {
  border: 2px dashed #E0B754;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.deal-content .img-thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
}
.deal-panel {
  position: relative;
  margin: -40px 0 -40px 0;
  border: 6px groove #96351A;
  border-style: groove;
  background: rgb(11, 87, 148);
  padding: 40px 20px;
}
.deal-panel .deal-header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  word-break: normal;
  color: white;
}
.deal-panel .deal-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
.deal-panel .text-block {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
.deal-panel .text-block h2 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 12px;
}
.deal-panel .text-block h2 a {
  line-height: 12px;
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}
.deal-panel .text-block h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.deal-panel .text-block span.deal-city {
  margin: 3px 0 5px 4px;
  display: block;
}
.deal-panel .text-block span.deal-city a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
.deal-panel .text-block span.deal-city a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 1px black;
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
}
.deal-panel .img-block {
  padding: 12px;
}
.deal-panel .img-block .img-rounded {
  width: 93%;
}
.deal-panel .btn-group {
  float: right;
  max-height: 20px;
}
.deal-panel i.icn-lrn {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/icons/icn-lrn.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
/* Button Mods */

a.btn {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #a6452b;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  color: #a6452b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus {
  background: #a12816;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* centered columns styles */

.row-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* reset the text-align */
  text-align: left;
  /* inline-block space fix */
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.col-fixed {
  /* custom width */
  width: 320px;
}
.col-min {
  /* custom min width */
  min-width: 320px;
}
.col-max {
  /* custom max width */
  max-width: 320px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .banner-head .banner-text {
    background-image: url('/img/landing/text-bg-white.png');
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: inherit;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .vrule {
    border-left: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .blog-panel .panel h2 {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 2px 0 5px;
  }
  .deal-panel .deal-header h3,
  .deal-panel .deal-header i {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .join_bar .text-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    right: 100px;
    height: inherit;
    width: 60%;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .join_bar {
    background-image: url('/img/join_bar_bg.jpg');
    position: relative;
    background-position: right top;
    padding: 30px 0 50px 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #F0EFEB;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .banner-head img {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .banner-head {
    background-position: left center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .banner-head .banner-text p {
    padding: inherit;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .blog-panel .panel {
    min-height: 240px;
  }
  .deal-panel {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 0;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .deal-panel:before,
  .deal-panel:after {
    content: none;
  }
  .join_bar .text-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
    width: 80%;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .banner-head {
    background: none !important;
  }
  .banner-head .banner-text p {
    margin: 30px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
  }
  .well h2,
  .well a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .join_bar {
    background-image: url('/img/join_bar_bg-transp.jpg');
    position: relative;
    background-position: right bottom;
    padding: 30px 0 50px 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #F0EFEB;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .well.container-fluid {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .deal-panel .deal-header h3,
  .deal-panel .deal-header i {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .deal-panel {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 25px 35px;
  }
  .deal-panel .btn-responsive {
    font-size: 110%;
  }
  .deal-panel .text-block {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .container {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .header .header-text {
    border-left: 0px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .blog-panel .panel {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .blog-panel .panel h2 {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .deal-panel {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .deal-panel .deal-header {
    left: 0px;
  }
  .join_bar .text-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 726px) {
  .deal-content .img-block {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
  }
  .deal-content .text-block {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }
  .deal-content hr.white {
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="join_bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum nulla odio. Mauris quis urna eu massa ultrices accumsan vel et libero. Ut gravida placerat tristique. Fusce enim metus, euismod eget feugiat tempor, scelerisque id turpis.
        Mauris
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subcats shadow-full" style="background-image: url('http://52.204.175.248/img/tool-bg2.png'); z-index: 1;">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Categories:</h2>

    <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-12 col-md-4 ayanEffects ayanHoverEffect_6">
      <li>
        <a href="#" style="font-size:16px;"> Plumbing Installation</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-12 col-md-4 ayanEffects ayanHoverEffect_6">
      <li>
        <a href="#" style="font-size:16px;"> Repair</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-12 col-md-4 ayanEffects ayanHoverEffect_6">
      <li>
        <a href="#" style="font-size:16px;"> Septic Tank</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Get Local Plumbers -->
<!-- Call to Action Well -->
<div class="well shadow-full" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>Certified Plumbers in your area:</h4>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the "effect7" style I found at this website:

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

I need the shadow to appear outside the container, not in it. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at how to create a [mcve]. Right now you've got a lot of code here and it's not clear where your problem lies.

Comment: Please pair down the markup to *minimal* requirements to show the issue. Don't make others spend 20 minutes trying to find that one class that's buried 300 lines down in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `:after` is responsible for the shadow behind the blue background of yours.

The below class is responsible for that.

```css
.shadow-full:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
  border-radius: 430px / 30px;
}
```

Either change the way of your implementation or remove the box-shadow for the `shadow-full:after`

Comment: its the border radius in `:after` . change `border-radius: 430px / 30px;` to `border-radius: 430px / 0px;` ... You won't get the circular vignette effect though.

Comment: Yeah, @AnkithAmtange is right! if you don't want the border inside the element, just change the border-radius.

Comment: Yeah, but the whole point of the effect is the rounded effect. Maybe its a lost cause :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you still want the box-shadow but don't want the effect to appear like it is overlapping your image.  If that's the case, the effect is coming from the border-radius and -moz-border-radius properties in the :before and :after of the shadow-full class:

```
.shadow-full:before, .shadow-full:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
   box-shadow: 0 0 40px 30px rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.18);
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
   border-radius: 430px / 30px;
}
```

Remove those styles to see the box-shadow on the outside only:

```
-moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
 border-radius: 430px / 30px;
```

However, that seems to be the entire point of that style to begin with, so you might want to try reducing the blur and spread radii (the third and fourth pixel values, respectively) in your box-shadow styles.

**EDIT:** Looks like I was beat to it by the comments in the other answer.  There's a good explanation there as well.